# Unable to parse content (XML expected) after export to .jar

Tags: java, xml, jar

In my program I download from server a XML file as String and sign it with certificate. Everything works fine when I run the program from Eclipse. But when I am exporting it to .jar file, the following  error occurs. Where should I look for the problem?

```
eu.europa.esig.dss.DSSException: Unable to parse content (XML expected)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.DomUtils.buildDOM(DomUtils.java:242)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.DomUtils.buildDOM(DomUtils.java:209)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.xades.signature.EnvelopedSignatureBuilder.buildRootDocumentDom(EnvelopedSignatureBuilder.java:75)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.xades.signature.XAdESSignatureBuilder.build(XAdESSignatureBuilder.java:179)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.xades.signature.XAdESLevelBaselineB.getDataToSign(XAdESLevelBaselineB.java:72)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.xades.signature.XAdESService.getDataToSign(XAdESService.java:92)
    at pl.btech.signer.Signer.signFilesWithMSCAPI(Signer.java:116)
    at pl.btech.signer.Signer.signXML(Signer.java:58)
    at pl.btech.signer.GuiController$1.run(GuiController.java:124)
Caused by: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.invalidByte(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.UTF8Reader.read(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.skipChar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at eu.europa.esig.dss.DomUtils.buildDOM(DomUtils.java:240)
    ... 8 more
```

EDIT:
It is fragment of code where error occurs. content is XML string which I get form server.

```
File srcFile = File.createTempFile("src", ".xml");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(srcFile);
writer.write(content);
writer.close();

DSSDocument doc = new FileDocument(srcFile));
ToBeSigned dataToSign = service.getDataToSign(doc, parameters);
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "But when I am exporting it to .jar file"? Please could you show us your signing code?

Comment: I meant that after export project to executable jar file I am getting this error. When I run project in Eclipse IDE error does not occur.

Comment: Okay... and what does the code look like?

Comment: Try changing `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(srcFile);` to `Writer writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(srcFile.toPath());`, so the content will be written in UTF-8 instead of the platform’s default charset.

Comment: Are you sure you have the neccessary permissions to write the temp file, when executing the jar on the command line?

Comment: And have you validated that `content` contains what you expect it to? Have you tried writing to a *non-temporary* file so that you can check that it contains what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileWriter` uses the default charset of the platform. This varies per application deployment, so that is not feasible. If the XML is always in UTF-8, do:

```
Path srcFile = Files.createTempFile("src", ".xml");
Files.write(srcFile, content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
// Or:
// Files.write(srcFile, Collections.singletonList(content));
```

Avoid FileWriter/FileReader.